# Binning not correct? Different amount of counts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two vectors of values, both with the same number of entries. Hence, when these vectors are histogrammed, the corresponding distributions should depict the counts vs values. I'm not sure whether I misinterpret something or plotted something wrong but in my understand the red values should not top the green values everywhere. When both vectors provide the same number of entries the one distribution must be lower than the other when the other is higher somewhere. Or not?

The plot command:

```
number_ticks<- function(n) {function(limits) pretty(limits, n)}

ggplot(data, aes(x = value, fill = Parameter)) +
geom_histogram(
binwidth = 0.25, 
color = "black",
alpha = 0.75) +
theme_classic() + 
theme(legend.position = c(0.21, 0.85)) + 
labs(title = "",
x = TeX("$ \\Delta U_{bias} / V"))) + 
scale_x_continous(breaks = number_ticks(20)) + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(title=Parameter))
```

[image: histogram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the red histogram goes on top of the green one: they are stacked. That is, `position = "stack"` is the default option in `geom_histogram`, while you want to use `position = "identity"`.

For instance, compare

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 500)
```

[image]

with

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, fill = cut)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 500, position = "identity", alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]